# UnitTesting with Mocking and Dependency Injection using Ninject

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, ninject, moq

I have the following scenario that I have not come across so far using Ninject. I have the following class structure (simplified for easy of reading :]). First the abstract base class for all `IDocument`s

```
public abstract class DocumentController : IDocumentController, IDisposable
{
    ...
    private IMessageBoxService messageBoxService;
    private IUndoRedoManager undoRedoManager;
    private FileSystemObserver observer;
    private bool fileChanging;

    public DocumentController(IMessageBoxService messageBoxService)
    {
        if (messageBoxService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("messageBoxService");

        this.messageBoxService = messageBoxService;
    }
    ...
    private void FileChangedHandler(string p)
    {
        if (!fileChanging && p.CompareNoCase(FilePath))
        {
            fileChanging = true;
            try
            {
                (View as Form).UIThread(() =>
                {
                    DialogResult result = messageBoxService.DisplayMessage(
                        (Form)View,
                        String.Format(
                            MessageStrings.DocumentController_DocumentChanged,
                            FilePath,
                            Constants.Trademark),
                        CaptionStrings.ChangeNotification,
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        if (TryClose(new FormClosingEventArgs(CloseReason.None, false)))
                        {
                            MediatorService.Instance.NotifyColleagues(
                                MediatorService.Messages.OpenDocuments,
                                new List<string>() { FilePath });
                            Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            finally
            {
                fileChanging = false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Omitted code for not saved prompt for brevity.
}
```

This class watches all documents that are open and if they are changed in the file system shows a prompt. If a close is attempted whilst they are in a "dirty" state, the same `IMessageBoxService` prompts to save.

An example of the derived concrete class ctors is

```
public class TextEditorController : DocumentController, IZoom
{
    ...
    public TextEditorController(ITextEditorView view, IMessageBoxService messageBoxService) 
        : base(messageBoxService)
    {
        if (view == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("view");

        this.view = view;
        InitializeEventHandlers();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now this works great when using the application. The problem I have is with unit testing. What I want to do is write a unit test that opens my text documents, makes some changes and then trys to close them when they are "dirty"/unsaved. This will show a message box, but I want to Mock the `IMessageBoxService` and test whether the message box is indeed displayed under the right conditions. I have the following unit test class

```
[TestClass]
public class DocumentManagementTests
{
    private IDocumentProvider documentProvider;
    private Moq.Mock<IProgress<string>> mockProgress;
    private List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();

    #region Initialization.
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        documentProvider = CompositionRoot.Resolve<IDocumentProvider>();
        if (documentProvider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("documentManager");

        mockProgress = new Mock<IProgress<string>>();
        mockProgress.Setup(m => m.Report(It.IsAny<string>()))
             .Callback((string s) =>
             {
                 Trace.WriteLine(s);
             });

        LoadTextDocumentFilePaths();
    }

    private void LoadTextDocumentFilePaths()
    {
        // Add two real file paths to filePaths.
        Assert.AreEqual(2, filePaths.Count);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DocumentChangedSavePromptTest()
    {
        // HOW DO I INJECT A MOCKED IMessageBoxService to `IDocumentController`?

        // Open the documents internally.
        var documents = documentProvider.GetDocumentViews(filePaths, mockProgress.Object);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, documentProvider.DocumentControllerCache
            .Count(d => d.GetType() == typeof(TextEditorController)));

        // Ammend the text internally. 
        foreach (var d in documentProvider.DocumentControllerCache)
        {
            var controller = d.Key as TextEditorController;

        }
        // Need to finish writing the test.
    }
}
```

So I want to know how I can inject a mocked `IMessageBoxService` into the ctor for the `IDocumentController` class?

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit. What I have come up with is the following test method.*

```
[TestClass]
public class DocumentManagementTests
{

    private Mock<IProgress<string>> mockProgress;
    private Mock<IMessageBoxService> mockMessageBoxService;

    private int messageBoxInvocationCounter = 0;
    private List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // Progress mock.
        mockProgress = new Mock<IProgress<string>>();
        mockProgress.Setup(m => m.Report(It.IsAny<string>()))
             .Callback((string s) =>
             {
                 Trace.WriteLine(s);
             });
        Assert.IsNotNull(mockProgress);

        // Load the file paths.
        LoadTextDocumentFilePaths();
    }

    private void LoadTextDocumentFilePaths()
    {
        string path = String.Empty;
        string directory = Utils.GetAssemblyDirectory();
        foreach (var fileName in new List<string>() { "DocumentA.txt", "DocumentB.txt" })
        {
            path = Path.Combine(directory, "Resources", "TextEditorDocs", fileName);
            if (!File.Exists(path))
                throw new IOException($"{path} does not exist");

            filePaths.Add(path);
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(2, filePaths.Count);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DocumentChangedSavePrompt_OnUserClosing_Test()
    {
        // Message box service mock.
        mockMessageBoxService = new Mock<IMessageBoxService>();
        mockMessageBoxService
            .Setup(m => m.DisplayMessage(It.IsAny<IWin32Window>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<MessageBoxButtons>(), It.IsAny<MessageBoxIcon>(), It.IsAny<MessageBoxDefaultButton>()))
            .Returns((IWin32Window owner, string text,
                string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton) => DialogResult.Cancel)
            .Callback((IWin32Window owner, string text,
                string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton) =>
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("MockMessageBoxService Invoked");
                messageBoxInvocationCounter++;
            });
        Assert.IsNotNull(mockMessageBoxService);

        // Open the documents.
        List<TextEditorController> controllers = new List<TextEditorController>();
        foreach (var path in filePaths)
        {
            TextEditorController controller = new TextEditorController(
                CompositionRoot.Resolve<ITextEditorView>(),
                mockMessageBoxService.Object);
            Assert.IsNotNull(controller);

            controllers.Add(controller);
            TextEditorView view = (TextEditorView)controller.Open(path);

            view.TextEditor.Text += "*";
            Assert.IsTrue(controller.IsDirty);
        }

        // Test they are dirty and the message box is displayed.
        foreach (var controller in controllers)
        {
            bool didClose = controller.TryClose(
                new FormClosingEventArgs(CloseReason.UserClosing, false));
            Assert.IsFalse(didClose);
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(2, messageBoxInvocationCounter);
    }
}
```

*This was based on the comments of Stephen Ross below. Is there any reason why I should not be creating concrete `TextEditorController`s?*

Comment: It looks like you're attempting mix an Integration test with a Unit test. You'd need to inject the mocked `IMessageBoxService` into your `CompositionRoot` in place of the actual `IMessageBoxService`. Otherwise create everything required for the `TextEditiorController` up front in the test instead of having to use the `CompositionRoot`, I'd rather you went with this option than having to use your actual `CompositionRoot`.

Comment: Can you clarify what "Integration Test" means in this context please? Also, are you suggesting I create a concrete version of `TextEditorController` and use mocked object in the constructor?

Comment: What I'm meaning is that you're mixing objects like your `CompositionRoot` in with a unit test, therefore it looks as though you want to test the interaction between modules (integration test), but then talk about mocking the dependencies to the System Under Test (closer to a unit test). If you are wanting to do a straight up unit test, yes I would say create a concrete `TextEditorController` and mock it's dependencies before calling the constructor.

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful. In a test class I build my `CompositionRoot` for all test classes via `[AssemblyInitialize] public static void Initialize(TestContext testContext){ CompositionRoot.Initialize(new DependencyModule()); }` So perhaps I should be using ctor injection in the test initialization. I am just concerned that creating a concrete implementation of a class is against DI and there is a better more "proper" way... Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: I used to be in the same mind as you that Dependency Injection means having an IOC Container like Autofac etc. But actually it simply means that the client delegates to external code to provide its dependencies instead of creating it's own services. Creating a concrete implementation is not at all against DI. Your test looks better, but the only thing I'd perhaps comment on is how much testing you are doing in 1 test case, it's not an issue but it may cause issues when adding functionality later.